# CSS Sprite not showing up

Tags: css, sprite

I have an image I want to put at the bottom of every post of my blog, but it's not showing up.

The image is part of a larger "icons.png" file I'm using to hold the stock images for my blog so I decided to just put it in as a sprite (since I'd have to do that for the other icons anyway).

HTML:

```
<section class="footnote">
    <p>This article is my <?php echo numeral(article_id()); ?> oldest. It is <?php echo count_words(article_html()); ?> words long, and it’s got <?php echo total_comments() . pluralise(total_comments(), ' comment'); ?> for now. <?php echo article_custom_field('attribution'); ?></p>
    <div class="sprite article-ender" ></div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.sprite {
    background-image: url(".../img/icons.png"); 
    display: block;
}
.sprite.article-ender {
    margin-top: 1em;
    background-position: -63px -563px;
    width: 46px;
    height: 99px;
}
```

I have noo idea what it is I'm doing wrong. I thought sprites were fairly simple but this image isn't showing up at all.

I thought maybe the image url was wrong, but I'm pretty sure I've got the relative URL right (yeah newbie here ahaha)--the img folder and my css folder (where the stylesheet is) are in the same folder.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you want to go "up" one folder, you shouldnt be using `background-image: url(".../img/icons.png"); `, remove one `.` from that path

Comment: @Andy, that was it exactly. Thanks! ^^"

Answer (score 2):

could be the three dots in front of the image url?

Comment: yeah, should be two. Thank you :)